# IIS front end of jboss

Tags: linux, windows, iis, iis-7, jboss

I wanted to know is it possible to place IIS 8 in front of two jboss 5 nodes hosting on Linux.Two jboss nodes are ruuning in cluster on two different machines.Is it possible for IIS to load balance and fail over the jboss servers.

Thanks,

Umar

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to know is it possible to place IIS 8 in front of two JBoss 5 nodes hosting on Linux.

It definitely is possible, as I've done it using IIS 7.5. The component that handles the load balancing and failover is called Application Request Routing (ARR). You will install it into the IIS server and then use it to create a server farm that will route requests to the JBoss servers.

Comment: I have also googled and came up with the following solutions;1) ISAPI Re director but it is difficult to implement and troubleshooting 2) As you mentioned ARR it is easy to configure but I am not confident whether it is suitable for production or not 3) boncode connector is a production option but I am unable to configure it properly.